# Is there a software to test a website in all browsers?

Tags: cross-browser

I want a software which installs most known browsers including ie 6 , and let me test my website like i'm on a browser to fix my css and make it cross browser. i know the online tools which gives you screenshots but that's not enough for me.

I need atlast to test it in IE 6/7/8 & Opera & Webkit

is there any similar software?

Comment: What about Gecko-based browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Well if online tools like [this one](http://browsershots.org/) are not enough, than you basically are looking for local tools, right? Why not use the browsers themselves then? Opera and Webkit should be accessible to anyone, as far as IE goes, there's a plugin for Chrome that renders like IE AFAIR (and there's a Chrome plugin for IE too).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Expression Web with Super Preview

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you: http://seleniumhq.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the web browsers you want to test in. To run multiple Internet Explorer instances you can use IETester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : http://spoon.net/browsers/

Answer (score 0):

We developed [Browsera](http://www.browsera.com), a cross-browser testing service, with exactly this scenario in mind.  We go quite a bit further than screenshots because Browsera automatically detects potential layout problems as well as functional problems such as scripting errors reported by the browser. While we don't cover as many browsers as Browsershots, we cover those most commonly used by the community.  Opera and Chrome support are coming soon.

LitmusApp, Browsershots, Superpreview, and Browserlab are all screenshot-based tools and don't do any problem auto-detection.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Testing – http://www.cloudtesting.com/ – offer a functional website testing tool that allows you to test your websites from the cloud. Enterprise users can download an agent which allows access to your local resources, i.e. inside your firewall/network.
It is based on Selenium, and allows you to capture scripts in the Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox, and then upload onto our servers for running.

We currently support the following browsers:

Firefox 2, 3 & 3.5
Internet Explorer 6,7 & 8
Safari 3.2 & 4.0
Chrome 2 and 3
Opera 9.6

With all of the above we capture full screenshots (i.e. of the browser window, not just the OS window), store the HTML and details of components on each page, along with timings and HTTP request and response headers. All of this is available to view via the results portal.

A free 7 day trial is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have multiple browser versions in your Windows environment, check this question: [Cross-browser testing: All major browsers on ONE machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/cross-browser-testing-all-major-browsers-on-one-machine#10541484)

> Aim of this guide:
>
> - Running multiple unmodified native versions of Internet Explorer,
>   Safari, Opera, Chrome and Firefox on a single machine, side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these websites:

http://browsershots.org/

https://browserling.com/

http://browsersnaps.tk/

http://netrenderer.com/

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser Testing tools

- http://browsershots.org/
- http://www.lunascape.tv/
- http://www.browsera.com/
- http://spoon.net/browsers/
- http://www.netrenderer.com/
- http://vanamco.com/ghostlab/
- http://www.anybrowser.com/siteviewer.html