# How to change/fake the 'file size'

Tags: file, resize, size, mp4

I have a file named "abc.mp4" its of 2 GB, i want a program that will conver it size to 6GB keeping the original video, Is there any method to do this like adding useless bytes at end of video?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you do, your original video will gets corrupted.

Comment: @PradeepSimha for testing, any way to do this without curropting?

Comment: stackoverflow is for coding and not for software suggestions.

Comment: @Loki Think before you say Please :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079350/is-there-a-software-to-test-a-website-in-all-browsers

Comment: @AsheshKumar [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079350/is-there-a-software-to-test-a-website-in-all-browsers) is about software that is to be used by software developers. Question like that can be on-topic *in some cases*. However, questions about software not used for development is almost never on topic on Stack Overflow, but some may be suitable for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer above is Good, But this Tool did my job very easily and perfectly!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/filesizefaker/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
    r.setLength(6L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    r.close();
```

Comment: It is Java and it is just a snippet, not a full program

Comment: Thank you for showing me a new Class that is quite useful. (I didn't know about `RandomAccessFile`)

Comment: AWESOME! Works like a pro! The full verison is it http://pastebin.com/ZMD9Xu7g